# Google Maps SDK for iOS issue when rotating to landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a Google Map from the Google Maps SDK for iOS (last version). I display a map like this in a `UIScrollerView`:

```
showMarker = YES;
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:[geocodeLatitude floatValue] longitude:[geocodeLongitude floatValue] zoom:13];
[self setupMapWithCamera:camera withLatitude:geocodeLatitude withLongitude:geocodeLongitude];

float mapHeight = 50;
[mapView_ setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, widthOfBlock, mapHeight)];
[self.scroller addSubview:mapView_];
```

The method called is:

```
-(void)setupMapWithCamera:(GMSCameraPosition *)camera withLatitude:(NSString *)Slatitude withLongitude:(NSString *)Slongitude {
    // setup map
    [mapView_ clear];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.settings.scrollGestures = NO;
    mapView_.settings.zoomGestures = NO;

    // setup marker
    if (geocodesuccess || showMarker) {
        GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([Slatitude floatValue], [Slongitude floatValue]);
        if ([ShopWithDatas.open isEqualToString:@"1"] || [ShopWithDatas.open2424 isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        } else {
            marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        }
        [mapView_ setSelectedMarker:marker];
        marker.map = mapView_;
    }    
}
```

So, it works when you enter in this view from Portrait => Portrait.
It works when you enter in this view from Landscape => Landscape.

But the camera is not centered anymore when you go from Portrait => Portrait and then in the view change to Landscape. Plus, It works when you enter this view from Landscape => Landscape and then turn into Portrait.

Any idea how to fix the camera for Portrait => Landscape issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, even if I don't get why it does not update correctly, I found this solution:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    if (canIshowMap) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D actualLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([geocodeLatitude floatValue], [geocodeLongitude floatValue]);
        GMSCameraUpdate *updatedCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:actualLocation];
        [mapView_ moveCamera:updatedCamera];
        //[mapView_ animateToLocation:actualLocation];        
    }
}
```

Please note that the commented line does not fix the bug.

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. The map camera still appears to be pointing somewhere off centre. It seems like the map bounds aren't properly updated after the interface orientation change.

Comment: Found the problem (at least in my case): needed to update to 1.9.0 of the SDK for use on iPhone 6/6+ and iOS8